# Show that the set of polynomials $P = \{p_k(x) = x^{5k + 4} + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1| k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ has a common non-trivial polynomial divisor

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that the set of polynomials 
$$P = \{p_k(x) = x^{5k + 4} + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1| k\in \mathbb{N}\}$$

has a non-trivial polynomial divisor.

The general form of the polynomials in $P$ can be factored as:

$$p_k(x) = x^{5k + 4} - x^4 + (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$$

$$=x^4((x^k)^5 - 1) + (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$$

Notice, $x^5 - 1|(x^k)^5 - 1$ and

$$x^5 - 1 = (x-1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$$

Therefore, $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 | p_k(x)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$

This is a very hard solution to see and requires a lot of practice in factoring polynomials. Is there any other easier solution?

Comment: They all vanish at $x=e^{2\pi i/5}$.

Comment: Using the Euclidean algorithm on any two particular candidates will give you a potential thing to check. Then, you will know what factorization you are looking for.